# Hibernate: mapping table row in different ways based on discriminator

Tags: hibernate

I am looking for an elegant way to map the following scenario with Hibernate.

Table 'A' has a one-to-many relationship with B (many B rows per one A row). B rows come in two types - 'Black' and 'White'. This type is designated by an integer discriminator column in B.

There will always be exactly one Black B row, and many White B rows. I'd therefore like to map Black B as a separate property on A, and map the remaining White Bs as a list.

I did a very quick test where I tried applying a table-per-class-hierarchy mapping strategy:

```
<class name="test.class.A" table="A_TABLE">
    <one-to-one name="blackItem" class="test.class.B" property-ref="parentA" />

    <set name="whiteItems" inverse="true">
        <key column="OID" />
        <one-to-many entity-name="WhiteB" />
    </set>
</class>


<class name="test.class.B" table="B_TABLE" discriminator-value="1">
    <id name="oid" type="long" column="OID">
        <generator class="sequence">bla</generator>
    </id>

    <discriminator column="B_TYPE_CODE" type="integer" />

    <many-to-one name="parentA" class="test.class.A" cascade="save-update">
        <column name="A_OID" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>

    <subclass name="test.class.B" discriminator-value="2" entity-name="WhiteB" />
</class>
```

This works correctly when I save, but there is a problem on find. When I retrieve A from the db, the A.whiteItems collection contains both the White and the Black B rows. The one-to-one correctly retrieves BlackB row, so BlackB ends up in both places.

Am I on the right track, or is there a better way to do this? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ok, really not sure why the descriminator is not being used when retrieving the rows, but a workaround is to use the 'where' attribute on the set:

```
<class name="test.class.A" table="A_TABLE">
<one-to-one name="blackItem" class="test.class.B" property-ref="parentA" />

<set name="whiteItems" inverse="true" where="B_TYPE_CODE=2">
    <key column="OID" />
    <one-to-many entity-name="WhiteB" />
</set>
```